# Clear a dynamically created div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a file input type that is used to select files. On the onchange event of the file selector I am displaying the selected file in a div with an [-] in front of them to detach that file from the div. Below is the code I am using to clear the div of the file with [-] sign:-

```
$.each(myFileList.files, function (i, val) {
        strFileNames += "<div id=\"" + myFileList.files[i].name.split(' ').join('_').split('.').join('_') + "\">" + myFileList.files[i].name + "<a class=\"removeFileUpload\" style=\"cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;\" title=\"Remove File from Upload List\" data-filename=\"" + myFileList.files[i].name.split(' ').join('_').split('.').join('_') + "\">[ - ]</a></div>";
});
```

Now on the click of class "removeFileUpload" i have another function as follows:-

```
function ehRemoveChosenFile() {
    $("body").on({
        click: function () {
            var fileName = $(this).data("filename");
            alert(fileName);
            var id = "'#" + fileName + "'";
            $(id).empty();
        }
    }, '.removeFileUpload');
}
```

But this function is not working.

I have also tried:-

```
$(id).replaceWith('');
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Regards
Abhishek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `id` variable is not a valid selector (because of the `'` quotes will have a value like `"'#demo'"`), change it in:

```
var id = "#" + fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = "'#" + fileName + "'";
```

The ID which you have appended is in single quotes which is not a valid selector.
This will consider as `$("'#yourId '")`

Change this to

```
var id = "#" + fileName;
```

then you can use either

```
$(id).empty();
        or
$(id).html('');
```